# Eclipse to color all occurances of an element in html file

Tags: eclipse, html, eclipse-plugin

While editing java files there is such a thing which highlights all the occurrences of the selected variable. Same thing exists in notepad++ for all the files, including html ones. In eclipse there is no such a thing for html files, or at least I dont know how to activate it[image: in this email as you see other occurrences of imageData did not get selected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for HTML is in the [Eclipse Webtools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). Just install and select the correct Editor.